# Restart a com+ application from command line

Tags: cmd, com+

How can I restart a com+ application from command line or a batch file?

Comment: Did you finally get a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Making use of the `COMAdminCatalog` facilities.

See [Basic Instinct: Automating COM+ Administration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985021.aspx) for getting knowledge about the COM+ Catalog.

And [COM+ Automation using C#](http://www.csharphelp.com/2007/02/com-automation-using-c/) for the code.